# How to fix "Cursor hides a field"?

Tags: java, coding-style, checkstyle

I have a SQLite query:

```
private String showAllType = "select * from tbl_Type";
```

And I call it as shown below:

```
Cursor mCursor = mSQLiteDB.rawQuery(showAllType, null);
```

But when I check codestyle, it gives a warning: `'mCursor' hides a field'`
 How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates, that you are using a local variable with the same name as a privously defined field. That is bad code design and should be avoided.

Rename your new `Cursor` variable to some other. `mSomething` is normally used for fields, not local variables.

Use `cursor` instead:

```
Cursor cursor = mSQLiteDB.rawQuery(showAllType, null);
// use 'cursor' for all the actions below
```

Comment: Thank FLX so much. I see the problem ! Because I define a total varible :  Cursor mCursor = null; so has that warning

Comment: hey @user2760991, if you want people answer your questions, you should accept them. this is the same for your other question. otherwise people will stop answering your. just press this arrow to make it green.